# Trying to Call Method From Different Swift Class

Tags: swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I have two swift classes and in one, I need to refer to a method in the other swift class. Both of the respective view controllers are attached to a `tabBarController`, so I tried to create an instance like such:

```
let mapVC : MapVC = self.tabBarController!.viewControllers![1] as! MapVC
mapVC.loadViewIfNeeded()
mapVC.add(newLocation:location_one) // .add is the method I want to call
```

Where `MapVC` holds the method I wish to call. And the `mapView` is the second option on the `tabBar`, hence the index of 1. However, I get the error `[fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value]` when I cast the object `mapVC`. I believe the problem has something to do with creating an instance `mapVC`, and I believe I may not have set it up properly, but I am not sure how to fix it.

I am not quite sure how to phrase my problem so if you are still confused, I can provide more information in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I normally do this with a custom `tabBarController` as the delegate for each tab, but I quite like your method of accessing the `viewControllers` in the stack. let's figure out whats wrong with your version.

**Try running it like this**

```
if let tC = self.tabBarController {
    if let vcs = tC.viewControllers {
        if let map = vcs[1] as? MapVC {
            print("map vc found in stack")
            map.loadViewIfNeeded()
            map.add(newLocation:location_one)
        } else {
            print("no map vc found at index 1")
        }
    } else {
        print("no stack found")
    }
} else {
    print("no tab bar found")
}
```

This might help us debug whats up with your code, are you sure it's the `mapVC` that is returning `nil`?

---

**Edit:** As you described in the comments, if you are segueing away from the `tabBarController` then the newly presented viewController's `tabBarController` property will be nil as per [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621169-tabbarcontroller).

> This property is nil if the view controller is not embedded inside a tab bar controller.

One solution would be to pass a reference of the `tabBarController` to `vc3` from `vc2` as per this diagram.

```
[tabBarController]
    |       |
  [vc1]   [vc2]  - both have a reference to tabBarController
            |
          [vc3]  - no reference yet
```

**Setup `vc3` to hold the tabBar reference**
- It's probably best to create a new var for this instead of using the existing `tabBarController` property.

```
class vc3:UIViewController {

    var tabBarReference:UITabBarController?

    func addALocation(location:CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        if let tbc = self.tabBarReference {
            if let map = tbc.viewControllers[1] as? MapVC {
                map.loadViewIfNeeded()
                map.add(newLocation:location)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Then inside `vc2` use the prepare for segue method to access `vc3` and give it the reference before it is presented.**

```
class vc2:UIViewController {

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let vc3 = segue.destinationViewController as? vc3
            vc3.tabBarReference = self.tabBarController
        }
    }

    func goToVC3() {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToVC3", sender: nil)
    }

}
```

I have not tested this code, but it should work in theory, let me know how you get on.

Comment: I implemented this into my code and it returned "no tab bar found". Which is what I thought was the issue, but it is rather strange because my view controllers are structured in a tabBarController. Do you know what is up?

Comment: @Kevin How are you adding the viewControllers to the tab bar?

Comment: The way I set up my tabBar is by originally using the default (2 tabs), then I added an tabBarItem to the bottom which segued to a third view controller. Does this answer your question? If you need more info, I'd be happy to provide it!

Comment: I think my issue is that the viewController that I am working with doesn't have a tab bar on the bottom. So I am trying to send information from a regular viewController to a tabBarController.

Comment: @Kevin I have updated my answer with an example of passing a reference of the tabBarController to the regular viewController. let me know if it helps.

Comment: I have implemented the code you suggested, but I received an error for the prepareForSegue. It is complaining about 'override', with "Method does not override any method from its superclass". I have tried removing the override part, and it still does not seem to be passing the information. Also, should I implement a segue between vc2 and vc3 with identifier "goToVC3"?

Comment: I have updated the answer, I think Swift 3 has a different implementation of the prepare for segue method.. might be worth auto filling it to make sure it is correct.. you can name your segues whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

I would add this safe array extension to your project first...

```
extension Collection where Indices.Iterator.Element == Index {

    /// Returns the element at the specified index iff it is within bounds, otherwise nil.
    subscript (safe index: Index) -> Generator.Element? {
        return indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
    }
}
```

Then... I would check if your view controller exists like this...

```
guard let mapVC : MapVC = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[safe: 1] as? MapVC else {
   print("could not find mapVC")
   return
}
mapVC.loadViewIfNeeded()
mapVC.add(newLocation:location_one)
```

Chances are that you are probably calling this method too soon. Sounds like either the tab bar or the controllers are not loaded. Try calling in in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

The two ways to achieve something like this are through delegate or notifications. In your case, I think you should look into notification and call then `add(newLocation:)` function upon notification.

Below is a quick example of one class invoking a function in another class. You can throw this in a playground and see how it works.

For view controllers, you generally start observing for events on `viewDidLoad` but depending on how you have structured your classes, other places might be better suited.

```
class MapVC {

    init() {
        print("Adding self as observer now...")
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(add), name: NSNotification.Name.init("addNewLocation"), object: nil)
    }

    @objc func add(notification: Notification) {
        guard let location = notification.object as? CLLocation else {
            return print("Did not recieve a CLLocation object in notification")
        }
        print("Got location with lat: \(location.coordinate.latitude), and lon:\(location.coordinate.longitude)")
        // your code for handling the addition of a new location
    }
}

class OtherVC {
    func add() { // however you're calling this function... you might be passing in a location here, but for demonstration, just creating a new one
        let location = CLLocation(latitude: 100, longitude: 100)
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name:     NSNotification.Name.init("addNewLocation"), object: location)
    }
}


let mapVC = MapVC()
let otherVC = OtherVC()

otherVC.add()
```

Comment: Could you explain further what notification is and how I can implement this?

Comment: @Kevin I have edited my response to include an example that you can throw in a playground to test out.

Comment: I like this concept of passing information through notifications. Your code has worked in the playground, but when I try to implement this into my file, it gives me a bunch of errors ( required initializer init(coder) must be provided by subclass of UIViewController). Is the implementation different compared to the playground?

Comment: @Kevin Correct, it's different. I have just made two classes not view controllers. Like I said in the edit, if you're not doing any fancy initialization with your view controller, you should move the register code in `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the NotificationCenter. 
You will need to register the notification listener in the class that you want to receive the notification and take action. And you need then to post the notification from the other class. You can do that like this :

```
 // Define identifier
let notificationName = Notification.Name("MyNotification")

// Register to receive notification
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(methodToCallWhenReceivingNotification), name: notificationName, object: nil)

// Post notification
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notificationName, object: nil)
```

Also in general you should register the notification in viewDidLoad() of the class you want receive it.